# Calling methods using an index over an array of methods

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a rather intricate logic that can fortunately be split over several cases, each implemented with a method, all methods having the same arguments and returning the same values. To avoid an unsightly if/elif sequence, I want to call the method by indexing an array with the case to process. I can do something like this:

```
class SomeClass(object):

    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name=name

    def method0(self,arg):
        print 'method0(%s,%s)' % (self.name,arg)

    def method1(self,arg):
        print 'method1(%s,%s)' % (self.name,arg)

    def method(self,i,arg):
        methods=[self.method0,self.method1]
        methods[i](arg)

foo=SomeClass('foo')
bar=SomeClass('bar')

foo.method(0,'covfefe')
bar.method(1,'covfefe')
```

However, this makes the array values bound to the instance. Out of curiosity, I wonder if there is a way to have unbound methods in the array: `methods=[method0,method1]` and bind them to the instance at call time. A syntax like `self.methods[case](args)` doesn't work (nor does initializing the array that way...).

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding what you're looking for.  Currently, the methods `method0` and `method1` use instance-level fields (`self.name`).  Are you looking for something like `def method(i, arg): SomeClass('foo').method(i, arg)`

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a case of the "variable variables" question. So let's abuse `getattr()`:

```
foo=SomeClass('foo')
bar=SomeClass('bar')

getattr(foo, 'method'+'0')('covfefe')
getattr(bar, 'method'+'1')('covfefe')
```

If you know you have a series of `foo, bar`:

```
series = (
     {'inst': SomeClass('foo'), 'i': 0},
     {'inst': SomeClass('bar'), 'i': 1})

for _ in series:
    getattr(_['inst'], 'method'+ str(_['i']))('covfefe')
```

I believe you can stick `getattr` in your class def:

```
def method(self,i,arg):
    L = ['method1','method2','method3']
    getattr(self, L[i])(arg)
```

Comment: Methods are called here `method{n}` for demonstration purposes, in the actual code they have descriptive names.